# How to bind a dataset to a sub-report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that takes one parameter, and works fine.

So I've put the report on another report as a subreport.

I have a dataset that returns several rows of names.

So I'm passing into the subreport as a parameter: Fields!Forename.Value and I want the subreport to repeat for every row the dataset returns.

When I run it the string 'Fields!Forename.Value' gets passed in as the parameter.

I know I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't seem to find anywhere on the UI to bind the my data set to the subreport to get this behaviour.

Sorry for the basic question, but this is really annoying me and its one of those things you can't google because the search terms you'd have to use are so broad.

Thanks for any help.

-Ian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a list that groups on the Fields!Forename.Value in your report. Then place the subreport in the list and pass the Field in as parameter. That should repeat the subreport for each name